# php ping a range ip address

Tags: php, database, ping

well i'm new of php and i have this problem....

```
<?php
$RANGE = 192.168.1.1/254;

for  in $RANGE
do
count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
if ! ping -c $COUNT $myhost; then
# 100% failed

fi
fi
done
echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAILID
```

the idea is :

- 1: ping the Range
- 2: mount an eventually server (if is alive)
- 3: send me an email
- 4: put all host alive in db

anyone can help me?!

tnx in advance

Comment: this is not even php :/ at least give it a go!

Comment: This is a shell script. Do you want its equivalent in PHP ?

Comment: What is your problem? What doesnt work, what do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You can check hosts and ports of hosts with fsockopen function

```
$hosts = array(/* array of hosts list */)

foreach ($hosts as $host) {
$hostname = $host;
$port = 80;
$timeout = 3;
$fp = fsockopen ($hostname, $port ,$errno ,$errstr, $timeout);
    if($fp) {
     // Port is alive 
     // Mount, send an email, insert to db
    } else {
     // Port is dead. Reason : $errstr
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess you could try something like this. Be warned though, I have not tested this code.

```
$mainpart = "192.168.1.";
$errors = array();
foreach(range(1, 254) as $ip) {
    $adr = $main . $ip;
    $msg = exec("ping {$adr} blablabla");
    if($msg == "bad error") {
        $errors[$adr] = $msg;
    }
}
```

Might need some sort of timeout for each loop. At the end you can loop through the errors-array to handle each error given. If possible I would consider using fsockopen to check on ports instead of pingcommands like Osaman recommends.